# how to find the subject and verb in the subordinate sentence

Tags: grammar

Q：
Please help me to understand where the subject s2 and the verb V2 in the subordinate sentence because I confuse in the string of "who I thought was".

[image]

Comment: Try writing it as two sentences that mean the same thing as the original sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a relative pronoun like "[who](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns)," it could be acting as the subject or the object of the following clause. In this case, the next verb is "thought," and "I" is its subject due to (1) form (*I* has to be a subject) and (2) proximity (*I* is closer to *thought* than *who*).

"I thought" forms the main subject and verb of the relative clause. What follows is a [reporting clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reporting-clause-1691911) serving as the subject of the reporting verb "thought." To illustrate, let us walk backward from writing this formation as a separate sentence, where "I thought" is the main subject and verb, "that" introduces the reporting clause, and "the student was your brother" is all subordinate:

> I thought that the student was your brother.

"That" is often omitted [in these constructions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-that-clause):

> I thought the student was your brother.

"The student" is the subject of "was" in the subordinate reporting clause. If it's added to the sentence before, repeating "the student" is repetitive and would merit a pronoun.

> On the bus I saw a student. I thought he was your brother.

One option is to make "he" a relative pronoun to introduce the second sentence as a relative clause, so "he" becomes "who" and fronts the clause to effectively connect "a student" to "who":

> On the bus I saw a student who I thought was your brother.